# How can I show the probability of lim(mean) = -1 is 1?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be random variables such that $X_n=n^2-1$ with probability $\frac{1}{n^2}$, and $X_n=-1$ with probability $1-\frac{1}{n^2}$. How can I show that
$$Pr\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_n\to -1\right)=1$$

I know that $X_n$ has mean 0 for all $n$, but they're not identically distributed. What if $X_1,X_2,...$ are mutually independent?

Comment: should follow by doing some simple tail bounds and borel cantelli

Comment: @Andrew Do you mind elaborating a little bit more? I'm trying my best to understand probability theory but I'm struggling.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ converges to $-1$ if $X_n = n^2-1$ for only finitely many $n$. Note $$\sum_{n\geq 1}P(X_n = n^2-1)= \sum_{n\geq 1}n^{-2}<\infty$$
, and an application of Borel-Cantelli implies $P(X_n = n^2-1\,\text{i.o.}) = 0$. Namely, we have shown $$P(n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i \to -1) \geq P(X_n = -1 \,\text{a.b.f.o}) = 1-P(X_n = n^2-1 \,\text{i.o.}) = 1$$ In fact, we have shown the stronger statement that if $P(X_n \neq -1)$ is summable, then $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i \to -1$ completely. For example, let $X_n = Y_n U_n-(1-Y_n)$ where $(U_n,Y_n)\sim \mathcal U[n^n,n^{2n}]\otimes \mathrm{Bern}(n^{-1}(\log n)^{-2})$. Then $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \to -1$ completely. In particular, the $X_i$ need not be independent.

The notation i.o. and a.b.f.o are shorthand for infinitely often and all but finitely often. We say a sequence of random variables $Z_n$ converges completely to a constant $c$ if $\tilde Z_n \to c$ almost surely for any sequence $(\tilde Z_n)$ satisfying $\tilde Z_n =_d Z_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand your argument.

Comment: The argument is essentially the first sentence. Which part exactly do you object to?

Comment: I don't understand why (−1∑=1→−1)≥(=−1a.b.f.o).

Comment: If $A$ implies $B$ then $P(A)\leq P(B)$.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!!